# C/C++ Hex char* to byte array

Tags: c++, c, hex, scanf

I've been trying to work out how to do this in embedded C++ for a while now, I've got a hex colour for a website in RGB888 eg "#ba00ff" that I want to convert into a C++ RGB555 hex value, eg 0x177C

Currently i've trimmed the # from the string and am stuck at converting it into a type I can use for creating the RGB555

my code currently looks like

```
 p_led_struct->color = "#ba00ff";
 char hexString[7] = {};
 memmove(hexString, p_led_struct->color+1, strlen(p_led_struct->color));
 byte colorBytes[3];
 sscanf(hexString,"%x%x%x",&colorBytes);
```

the hexString value becomes "ba00ff" correctly although the colorBytes array has incorrect data.

any assistance on how I should do this conversion would be awesome :)

Thanks!

Comment: If you skip the first char, don't you need to subtract 1 from the string length?

Comment: I believe the end of string '/n' makes "ba00ff" 7 chars, i'm not sure if a char array without a end of string char in sscanf will cause an error. **Edit** sorry I meant 'Null-terminated' `\0` not `/n`

Comment: '/n' is newline character, not the terminator. There is no newline in your string.

Comment: But I rarely use C strings so maybe I am wrong about the string length.

Comment: `memmove` is fine; It is good to have `'\0'` at the end of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems with `sscanf(hexString,"%x%x%x",&colorBytes);` are:

1. `sscanf` expects you to give 3 `int`s as a parameter but only one array is given and it is not `int`.
2. Single `%x` reads more than 2 characters.

Try:

```
int r, g, b;
if(sscanf(hexString,"%2x%2x%2x", &r, &g, &b) != 3) {
     // error
}
```

**Edit:**

Very useful info on scanf-family: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

Comment: Awesome, this worked perfectly, thanks for explaining how to use sscanf properly!

Answer (score 2):

Convert `p_led_struct->color` to an integer

```
p_led_struct->color = "#ba00ff";
unsigned int colorValue = strtoul(p_led_struct->color+1, NULL, 16);
```

and convert this RGB value into RGB555. The RGB integer has fields 0000.0000.rrrr.rrrr.gggg.gggg.bbbb.bbbb, and RGB555 has fields 0rrr.rrgg.gggb.bbbb, so we need only bit shifting:

```
unsigned short rgb555 = ((colorValue & 0x00f80000) >> 9) +  // red
  ((colorValue & 0x0000f800) >> 7) +  // green
  ((colorValue & 0x000000f8) >> 3);  // blue
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `hh` modifier to scan directly into 1 byte.

```
p_led_struct->color = "#ba00ff";
byte colorBytes[3];
int result;
result = sscanf( p_led_struct->color, "#%2hhx%2hhx%2hhx", &colorBytes[0], 
    &colorBytes[1], &colorBytes[2]);
if (result != 3) {
  ; // handle problem
}
```

After you successfully scan the 3 RGB 8-bit bytes, recalculate the 3x5bit result.

```
int r,g,b;
r = colorBytes[0] >> 3;
g = colorBytes[1] >> 3;
b = colorBytes[2] >> 3;
printf("%04X", (r << 10) | (g << 5) | (b << 0));
```

Comment: typo in your last line, now you get a red-based gray scale :)

Comment: @Jongware Thanks and fixed.  Now the only thing red is my face. :)

Comment: Thanks Chux, i'm trying to understand the solution should 
`result = sscanf( p_led_struct->color, "#%2hhx%2hhx%2hhx", &colorBytes[0], &colorBytes[0], &colorBytes[0]);`
be `&colorBytes[0], &colorBytes[1], &colorBytes[2]` or all references to the first address?

Comment: @Tim Kalinowski Yet another oops.  Thanks for pointing it out.